# different 'select all' checkboxes for different lists of checkboxes, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

On my page I have a three list of checkboxes. Each list has an own checkbox "select all". I do not want to increase code with duplicating lines, that's why I'm using the same function with parameter to select certain list of checkboxes

```
      $scope.selectAll = function(array) {
            angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
                 item.Selected = $scope.model.selectedAll;
             });
       };
```

html

```
   <input type="checkbox"
            ng-model="model.selectedAll" 
            ng-change="selectAll(categories)" >
```

It gives me desirable result, I can select all checkboxes in certain array.
But here is the problem. `$scope.model.selectedAll` related to all lists and when I select all at the one list, checkbox "select all" is checked in all lists.

I clearly understand this problem, I just don't have any idea how to resolve it. I have been thinking about creating of 3 different variables for each list but I'm using function with parameter, where array is unknown, so I cannot associate certain variable with it and it won't be working.

Is there any way to resolve this problem without duplicating code for particular list of checkboxes?

thanks in advance.

[here is my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IlK3Lblsk4TNj3bnb26J?p=preview)

Comment: Couldn't you pass a boolean into `$scope.selectAll()` to choose whether to select or deselect instead of looking up a DOM node inside the function?

Comment: @ebyrob if I'm passing boolean, the binging will be only one way, it will false or true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've done this binds a set of non-related entities to the same model, which means that you've bound them very tightly. Obviously the goal is to keep them separated, so you'll need a different model, and there are a few ways to do that.

**Using Entirely Unique Models**

One way to do this is to just make your code a little more general and then a series of unique models associated with each checkbox, like so:

*html*

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="model1.selectedAll" 
       ng-change="selectAll(categories1, model1.selectedAll">
```

*JS*

```
$scope.selectAll = function(array, value) {
  angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
    item.Selected = value;
  });
};
```

**Using a Base Model**

Alternatively,if you don't want to keep track of multiple variables, you can encapsulate them into a single base. This method is useful if you have dynamically-created elements.

*html*

```
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-model="modelSet[key].selectedAll" 
       ng-change="selectAll(categories, key)">
```

*JS*

```
$scope.selectAll = function(array, key) {
  angular.forEach(array, function(item) {
    item.Selected = $scope.modelSet[key].selectedAll;
  });
};
```

Whatever you do, note that your selection function is getting more information from the view and less information from the $scope. You want to provide your utility function with as much context as possible so that it can reused more reliably.

Comment: Thank you Dominic, the second way is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help :)